# Complex query string with subarrays into restangular getList params

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, restangular

I have a complex query string I'm trying to convert into a restangular getList() method which returns a promise object.  The query string is currently formatted like so (and the endpoint likes it):

```
?Columns[0].key=FirstName
&Columns[0].value=p
&Columns[1].key=LastName
&Columns[1].value=p
&Joins[0].table=Role
&Joins[0].key=Name
&Joins[0].value=admin
&sortdirection=asc
&sortColumn=Name
```

How would I format the params object below in order to get the getList method to have that returned?

`Restangular.all('users').getList(params);`

I've tried numerous ways to format this as Json, and while Restangular did put the values into the query string, it was formatted in such a way that the endpoint didn't recognize the array elements, only the sortdirection and sortcolumn elements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can take a look at the [getList method definition](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#element-methods) on the official Restangular Github. As you can see, if you need to use parameters, you have to inquire the **subElement** property :

```
Restangular.getList('users',params);
```

In order to send properly your query-params, you need to build a clean json object. In your case:

```
var params = { 'columns' : [{'key':'FirstName','value': 'p'},  {'key':'LastName','value':'p'}],
               'joins': [{'table' : 'Role', 'key' : 'Name', 'value': 'admin'}],
               'sortdirection':'asc',
               'sortColumn': 'Name'
             }
```

Comment: Yes, that is initially what I did; however the array objects are not getting model bound on the WebAPI endpoint properly.  The query string looks like this: {/users?columns={"key":"FirstName","value":"p"}&columns={"key":"LastName","value":"p"}&sortColumn=&sortdirection=}